# No associated item named wrap_under_create_rule found for type CGContext when using core-graphics

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use Quartz2D from Rust in a Mac app through the core-graphics crate, but I'm having trouble using core-graphics. I can obtain a `CGContextRef` to the current context with:

```
let cg_context_ref: CGContextRef = unsafe {
    let ns_graphics_context: *mut Object = msg_send![Class::get("NSGraphicsContext").unwrap(), currentContext];
    msg_send![ns_graphics_context, CGContext]
}
```

Then, I attempt to construct a `CGContext` from the `CGContextRef` using [`wrap_under_create_rule`](https://github.com/servo/core-graphics-rs/blob/master/src/context.rs#L76), which comes from [`pub trait TCFType` from core-foundation](https://github.com/servo/core-foundation-rs/blob/44e872a427120f2e35c4d6ca4e02ee33f0ca798a/core-foundation/src/base.rs#L52):

```
let gc: CGContext = unsafe {
    CGContext::wrap_under_create_rule(unsafe {
        let ns_graphics_context: *mut Object = msg_send![Class::get("NSGraphicsContext").unwrap(), currentContext];
        msg_send![ns_graphics_context, CGContext]
    })
};
```

However, compiling gives this error:

```
error: no associated item named `wrap_under_create_rule` found for type `core_graphics::context::CGContext` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:45:9
   |
45 |         CGContext::wrap_under_create_rule(unsafe {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope; the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
   = help: candidate #1: `use core_foundation::base::TCFType;`
```

I already have `use core_foundation::base::TCFType;`, and in the same scope, though. It looks like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate objc;
extern crate core_foundation;
extern crate core_graphics;

use objc::runtime::{Object, Class};
use core_foundation::base::TCFType;
use core_graphics::context::CGContext;

fn main() {
    let gc: CGContext = unsafe {
        CGContext::wrap_under_create_rule(unsafe {
            let ns_graphics_context: *mut Object = msg_send![Class::get("NSGraphicsContext").unwrap(), currentContext];
            msg_send![ns_graphics_context, CGContext]
        })
    };
}
```

I'm a bit of a Rust noob, so I got stuck here. Why won't this work, and how can I make it work? Modifying core-graphics is an option, since I'm going to have to do it later down the road anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are good that you are dealing with two different versions of `TCFType`. Following your example, I saw the same error. I then ran [cargo-tree](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-tree):

```
$ cargo tree
cg v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/cg)
├── core-foundation v0.4.0               <---- here
│   ├── core-foundation-sys v0.4.0
│   │   └── libc v0.2.23
│   └── libc v0.2.23 (*)
├── core-graphics v0.8.1
│   ├── bitflags v0.8.2
│   ├── core-foundation v0.3.0           <---- here
│   │   ├── core-foundation-sys v0.3.1
│   │   │   └── libc v0.2.23 (*)
│   │   └── libc v0.2.23 (*)
│   └── libc v0.2.23 (*)
└── objc v0.2.2
    └── malloc_buf v0.0.6
        └── libc v0.2.23 (*)
```

From this, I can see that core-graphics is depending on core-foundation 0.3.0, but your crate depends on core-foundation 0.4.0.

Types provided by two different versions of crates **are not the same**, and the compiler tells you so. It just doesn't tell you that the versions differ.

To fix it, restrict your version of core-foundation to 0.3.0. Doing this caused this error to go away for me, but then there were some unrelated errors that were previously hidden.